# How to create a list of numbers which are multiples of 3 and fall between a specific range?

Tags: r, random

I am new to `R` and would appreciate any help on this 2 step task.

I need to write the `R` codes to create a list of numbers which are mutiples of `3`  between `1` and `40`.

The second part would need the codes to randomly select `6` numbers from the list above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate number multiple of `3` try `seq` with `by=3`. And then use `sample` to pick `6` random samples out of that sequence. I have used `set.seed(1)` to get fixed output:

```
set.seed(1)
sample(seq(3,40,by=3), 6)
#[1] 12 15 21 30  6 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in a step-by-step manner:

```
# 1. List of numbers between 1 and 40
list_numbers <- seq(1:40)

# 2. Filter
list_filter <- sapply(list_numbers, function(x) {x %% 3 == 0})

# 3. List of numbers multiple 3
list_numbers_multiple_3 <- list_numbers[list_filter]

# 4. Select 6 random numbers
sample(list_numbers_multiple_3, 6)
```